# Proving that the doubling time for an exponentially increasing quantity is constant for all time

Tags: calculus

How do I prove this **for all time?**

I know that if I were to prove it for only the starting condition (i.e. the time it takes to double for the first time only) would be as follows:

If $A(t) = A_0e^{kt}$ and $A(T) = A_0e^{kT} = 2 A_0$ then $T = \frac{\ln 2}{k}$

I.e., I've only proved it takes T time to go from $A_0$ to $2A_0$. But what about $2A_0$ to $4A_0$ and etc?

Comment: Show that ${A(t+T) \over A(t)}$ is a constant.

Comment: It you prove it once, then you have proved it for all time, that's the beauty of mathematics :-).

Comment: And I see the beauty @copper.hat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what the difference is? Given any $A(t_1)$ you simply need to compute that $A(t_1 + T) = 2A(t_1)$, where T is what you just computed.

Comment: Yes this should help you @Jason and you will get the same time.

Comment: Ah, so is it true that my current proof is incomplete? Once I prove that A(t+T) = 2A(t) it is complete?